# Locked out of SQL Server due to trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have accidentally run the following trigger on SQL Server 2012. How do I reverse it?

The trigger was intended to block certain IP addresses, but has blocked the entirety. I can't seem to log in anywhere.

```
CREATE TRIGGER block_ipaddress
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @capturedip NVARCHAR(15);

    SET @capturedip = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(15)'));

    IF EXISTS(SELECT ipaddress FROM master.dbo.IPBLock WHERE ipaddress = @capturedip)
    BEGIN
        Print 'Your IP Address is blocked, Contact Administrator'
        ROLLBACK
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @IPRange VARCHAR(15)

        SELECT @IPRange = SUBSTRING(@capturedip,1,LEN(@capturedip)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@capturedip)))+'.*'

        IF EXISTS(SELECT ipaddress FROM master.dbo.IPBLock WHERE ipaddress = @IPRange)
        BEGIN
            Print 'Your IP Address Range is blocked, Contact Administrator'
            ROLLBACK
        END
    END
END
GO
```

I am no longer connected to the database. I obtained the information from this website: 
http://sql-articles.com/articles/security/ip-address-blocking-or-restriction-in-sql-server/

Comment: last time i was locked out due to permission problems i had to change the instance to single user mode and then i could connect and make changes..  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

Comment: Do you have the dedicated administrator Connection enabled? Also, can you RDP into the machine?

Comment: try `sqlcmd -S server_name -U sa -P pass_word -A -d master -q "drop trigger block_ipaddress ON ALL SERVER"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the fine documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx)

> When a logon trigger is preventing connections, members of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role can connect by using the dedicated
>   administrator connection, or by starting the Database Engine in
>   minimal configuration mode (-f) For more information, see [Database Engine Service Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx) .

Then once connected you can drop the trigger.

Comment: Problem resolved thank you. Logged into the server using administrator connection on command prompt and dropped the trigger by name.